# Jest: Create a generic mock where I can pass the custom data

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am using the following in all my individual test case files which runs successfully.

```
jest.mock('next-i18next', () => {
    return {
        useTranslation: () => {
            return {
                t: (key) => {
                    const translations = {
                        title: 'May I help?',
                        showErrors: 'Something went wrong.',
                        noResultFound: `Oops`,
                    };
                    return translations[key];
                },
            };
        },
    };
});
```

The translations change based on different test cases and hence I had duplicated them everywhere I need.
But I want to modify this so that this mock becomes generic(maybe by creating a function) that sits in one place while I call this created function from all the test case files I need and pass my custom dictionary to it. Something like this but it doesn't work:

```
const mockTranslations = (mockdictionary) => ({
  jest.mock('next-i18next', () => {
    return {
      useTranslation: () => {
        return {
          t: (key) => {
            return mockdictionary[key];
          },
        };
      },
    };
  })
})
```

I am not sure if it is possible to do in Jest, still trying to figure out. Any help here or other approach of doing it will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two strategies :

- modify your mock, so the `t` function always returns the translation key (basically, `t: (key) => key`). In your tests, check that the correct translation key is present in the DOM (`expect(getByText("myTranslationKey")).toBeTruthy()`). So you can validate that the correct key is used, but not that the corresponding text is correct,
- do not mock react-i18next in your test, even better :). More realistic, more confidence. If you load JSON files dynamically, you will need to modify your react-i18next configuration for the Jest tests. In a [Jest configuration file](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration), add :

```js
// assuming that you have multiple JSON files in /public/locales/en
import * as namespaces from '/public/locales/en';

i18next.use(initReactI18next).init({
  [...]
  lng: 'en',
  resources: { en: namespaces },
});
```

So now you can test you real texts in Jest suites.